# How to show more of the buffer in the current window?

Tags: scrolling

Sometimes I have the current buffer in the current window displayed sub-optimally: there is a lot of
buffer not shown, and there is a lot of empty space at the bottom below the EOB.
E.g.:

- the buffer is 100 lines
- the window is 10 lines
- the point is on the line 3 of the window
- EOB is on the line 5 of the window

so that the bottom 5 lines of the window are empty and the first 95 lines of the buffer are not
shown.

I want a function that would "move the window 5 lines up along the buffer" so that

- the EOB is on the bottom line of the window
- the last 10 lines of the buffer are shown
- the point is on the line 8(=3+5) or the window, the value of `(point)` did *not* change

Note:

- I do *not* want the point to move
- I do *not* want to change window configuration
- I do *not* want to change the current window size

I am pretty sure something like that exists already, I just cannot figure out how to find it.

Edit:

Apparently, I need something like this:

```lisp
(defun sds-improve-window-utilization ()
  "Ensure that there is no empty space below EOB in the current window"
  (interactive)
  (when-let ((w (selected-window))
             (eob-pos (cadr (pos-visible-in-window-p (point-max) w t)))
             (point (cadr (pos-visible-in-window-p (point) w t)))
             (height-c (window-total-height w))
             (height-p (window-pixel-height w)))
    (recenter (/ (- point eob-pos) (/ height-p height-c)))))
```

I wonder, again, if something like that already exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to move EOB to the bottom of the window without moving point, then the simplest thing I can think of is

```
(save-excursion
   (goto-char (point-max))
   (recenter-top-bottom (window-height)))
```

It's effectively a no-op if the EOB is not visible in the window and otherwise saves point, positions EOB at the bottom of the window and restores point.

Comment: Nah, this still leaves a few un-used lines at the bottom ;-(

Comment: What's the value of `scroll-margin`? Try let-binding it to 0 around the `recenter` call.

Comment: `scroll-margin` is 0

Comment: Then it's probably because EOB is on an empty line after the last visible text. If you have trailing newlines, try deleting them; although if you insist on having a final newline (which is always a good idea IMO), there is going to be an empty line at the bottom: you'd have to position EOB on the line given by `(1+ (window-height))` - you might try that, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 0):

Use `recenter-top-bottom`, normally bound to `C-l`.

Comment: Nope, `C-l` makes the current line center, but there is still empty space at the bottom.

Comment: Hit `C-l` twice more. Seriously.

Comment: I know how `C-l` works, I tried it and I read the code. It does _NOT_ do what _I_ need. I want ***EOB*** to be the bottom of the window,  not the ***point***.

Comment: I think you’re being particular enough that you’re going to have to write your own.